# Zend Framework route for generic pages?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-router

I'm building a Zend Framework sites. It's MVC, so uses controllers so I have controllers like `NewsController` that is accessed via **/news** etc. However, another of my controllers is `PagesController`, which handles just static content pages.

My `PagesController` is also my default controller. So **http://example/** returns `PagesController::home()`. I also have a method called `view()` that takes `$slug` as a parameter.

What I'd like to do is set up a route whereby if I request **http://example.com/about** and there isn't a `NewsController`, that the request is passed to the `view()` method of my `PagesController`.

I'm a Zend Framework n00b so have no idea where to start with this. Is this possible? If so, how could I achieve this?

Comment: When you say "there isn't a NewsController" do you mean news controller can't handle it or there's no physical file NewsController.php present?

Comment: I just mean by Zend Framework's default routing. So if I requested **/news**, then it would look for `NewsController`. Basically, if the default routes all miss, I then want the request passed to my `PagesController` to try and find a content page in the database, and if there isn't one there to throw the normal 404 error page.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this before on [Zend Framework website.com/username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895115/zend-framework-website-com-username/6914842#6914842) by using a plugin. In that plugin, you can just replace `$username` with your slug and change the request params as needed.