# Zend Framework: How can i pass values to layout.phtml?

Tags: zend-framework

I can pass value from controller to view with this =>

```
$this->view->objvalue = $value;
```

But how can i pass value to layout.phtml ?

I want to have a link to edit table. So i have to make the link with 'id'=>$getvaluefromsomewhere->id. How can i do this in zend framework ?

Where would i put this file (My_Layout_Plugin.php) ?

```
class My_Layout_Plugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
   public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
   {
      $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
      $view = $layout->getView();

      $view->whatever = 'foo';
   }
}
```

[Sending variables to the layout in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537700/sending-variables-to-the-layout-in-zend-framework)

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537700/sending-variables-to-the-layout-in-zend-framework

Comment: I edited that original question. Where would i put that plugin file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put it in library/My/Layout/Plugin.php and add this in application.ini

```
resources.frontController.plugins.layout = "My_Layout_Plugin"
```

See here [Zend framework 1.8 recommended way to register a plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938930/zend-framework-1-8-recommended-way-to-register-a-plugin)